# Customize asp.net-identity error strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Im try to personalice strings Errors of asp.net-identity, this is my code:

```
    private async Task< bool> addUser()
    {

        using (libProduccionDataBase.Contexto.DataBaseContexto context = new DataBaseContexto())
        {
            using (var t = new libProduccionDataBase.Identity.ApplicationUserManager( new libProduccionDataBase.Identity.ApplicationUserStore( context ) ))
            {

                ApplicationUser usr = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Nombre = AddNombreKTbox.Text,
                    ApellidoPaterno = AddApPaternoKTbox.Text,
                    ApellidoMaterno = AddApMaternoKTbox.Text,
                    ClaveTrabajador = AddClaveKTbox.Text,
                    UserName = AddLoginNameKTbox.Text,
                    Email = AddEmailKTbox.Text
                };

                IdentityResult result = await  t.CreateAsync(usr, AddPasswordKTbox.Text);

                if (result.Succeeded) t.AddToRole( usr.Id, "Usuario General" );
                foreach(var err in result.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( err );
                }
                return result.Succeeded;
            }
        }
    }
```

But i need the errors in Spanish, for example if password as empty,  result.Errors[0] gave me "Passwords must be at least 6 characters.", but i need personalice the string to Spanish, this is an example but, i need  change to spanish all errors messages.

Comment: Reading about localization is your way to go. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved the problem**

first tryed to validate ApplicationUser directly, but the text of errors show in english, so, i decided create a class with DataAnotations, then i validate this on the method, if the validatio as true, proceded to create a new user, if not valid, return false.

this is the Class:

```
public class CreatingUserModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="El nombre para inicio de sesion es Requerido")]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage ="El Nombre para inicio de sesion debe contener al menos 6 caracteres")]
    public string LoginName { get; set; }


    [Required( ErrorMessage = "El Nombre del usuario es requerido" )]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }


    [Required( ErrorMessage = "El Apellido Paterno del usuario es requerido" )]
    public string ApellidoPaterno { get; set; }


    [Required( ErrorMessage = "El Apellido Materno del usuario es requerido" )]
    public string ApellidoMaterno { get; set; }


    [MaxLength( 10, ErrorMessage = "El largo maximo para la clave del trabajador es de 10 caracteres" )]
    public string ClaveTrabajador { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage ="El Email es requerido")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="No es un email Valido")]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Required( ErrorMessage = "La contraseña es requerida" )]
    [MinLength( 6, ErrorMessage = "La contraseña debe ser de al menos 6 caracteres" )]
    public string Contraseña { get; set; }


    [Required( ErrorMessage = "La confirmacion de la contraseña es requerida" )]
    [Compare(nameof(Contraseña), ErrorMessage ="La contraseña confirmada no coincide")]
    public string ConfirmeContraseña { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ToApplicationUser()
    {

        return new ApplicationUser
        {
            Nombre = this.Nombre,
            ApellidoPaterno = this.ApellidoPaterno,
            ApellidoMaterno = this.ApellidoMaterno,
            ClaveTrabajador = this.ClaveTrabajador,
            UserName = this.LoginName,
            Email = this.Email
        };

    }
}
```

and,  to use:

```
private async Task< bool> addUser()
    {

        using (libProduccionDataBase.Contexto.DataBaseContexto context = new DataBaseContexto())
        {
            using (var t = new libProduccionDataBase.Identity.ApplicationUserManager( new libProduccionDataBase.Identity.ApplicationUserStore( context ) ))
            {


                CreatingUserModel _usr= new CreatingUserModel
                {
                    Nombre = AddNombreKTbox.Text,
                    ApellidoPaterno = AddApPaternoKTbox.Text,
                    ApellidoMaterno = AddApMaternoKTbox.Text,
                    ClaveTrabajador = AddClaveKTbox.Text,
                    LoginName= AddLoginNameKTbox.Text,
                    Email = AddEmailKTbox.Text
                };

                ValidationContext validator = new ValidationContext(_usr);
                List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
                bool valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(_usr, validator, results, true);
                if (valid)
                {
                    var usr= _usr.ToApplicationUser();

                    IdentityResult result = await  t.CreateAsync(usr, AddPasswordKTbox.Text);

                    if (result.Succeeded) t.AddToRole( usr.Id, "Usuario General" );


                    return result.Succeeded;
                }else
                {
                    StringBuilder strbld = new StringBuilder();
                    results.ForEach( err => {
                        strbld.AppendFormat( "•{0}\n", err.ErrorMessage );
                    } );

                    Console.WriteLine( strbld.ToString() );
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```